# blocks to regions(like drupal) templating system for nodejs express framework

Tags: design-patterns, node.js, express

I'm using nodejs **express** framework. There are 2 separate express apps (auth and service), they are merged with **connect** npm module **vhost** module like this:

```
    // merge apps
    express.createServer()
    // subdomain parser
    .use(function(req, res, next){
      req.subdomain = getSubdomain(req.headers.host);
      next();
    })
    .use(express.vhost('auth.' + domain, authApp))
    .use(express.vhost('*.' + domain, serviceApp))
    .listen(port);
```

I want to make shared between apps template regions(header, sidebar, footer etc..) and fill regions with provided by apps template blocks (Something like php Drupal theme system).

How to make it better without antipatterns? Maybe there are already some useful module?

Comment: And I'm using jade template engine

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a template engine for express, note the [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/). It is a  [common way](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#view-rendering) for express. You can use some templates shared between both apps. Jade is often used with [Stylus](http://learnboost.github.com/stylus/).